# Why prevState is equal to this.state in componentDidUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have **stateUpdater** like this

```
stateUpdater(field, val){
    let obj = {...this.state.json}
    obj[field] = val
    this.setState({json: obj})
  }
```

(It is passed to children components from Main so I can update Main state on lower-level events.)

And I have **componentDidUpdate** like this

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    console.log(prevState.json.ingredient_groups)
    console.log(this.state.json.ingredient_groups)
    ...
 }
```

So when I **delete an element** from array in json.ingredient_groups it logs

```
Array[7]
Array[7]
```

but expected behavior is

```
Array[8]
Array[7]
```

**TRIED TO:**

- Make a copy of **obj** in stateUpdater using **spread operator**, **JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))**, **Object.assign({}, obj)**
- Update state

like this

```
 stateUpdater(field, val){
    let obj = {...this.state.json}
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
        return {json: Object.defineProperty(obj, field, val)}
    })
 }
```

- Use **getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()**

None of these helped

Comment: Can you please provide structure of `this.state.json`?

Comment: @Fyodor here it is
`recipe_subcategories: Array[0]  

recipe_user_tags: Array[1]  
servings: 4  
setting_commentable: true  
setting_rateable: true`

Comment: This expression `obj[field] = val` sets some property of `obj` equal to `val`. So `val` should contain full array. Where fo you call `stateUpdater` and what value of `val` is passed?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that JS passes **primitives**(numbers, booleans, strings) **by values** and **objects**(also arrays) **by reference**.

So when you work with complicated state object  and pass objects as props to child components - it's really easy to mutate upper-level state.

For me it was input-field-change-handler like this

```
handleInput(e) {
    let data = this.state.data
    data.input = e.target.value
    this.setState({data})
}
```

Because data from this.state is an object, it's passed by reference
And state is mutated at line

```
data.input = e.target.value
```

before setState occures.